# displaying double variable problem (Arduino)

Tags: arduino-uno, display

so I have a problem with displaying a double variable in OLED & IR remote calculator, like this (using u8g2):

```
displayTextOnRight(String(100000, 0)); //ex. of an void and a number
```

It displays: " "
But when I set to ex. 99999 it displays: "99999"

The same is with

```
displayTextOnRight(String(1000.00, 2));
```

It also displays nothing. (100.00 displays 100.00)

I tried values below zero and it crashes. When I try 6 it's empty whatever I type on my remote.

Please help.

Comment: What's this "displayTextOnRight()" function? What code are you using? Where did you get it? What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

When the first argument to the [String](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) constructor is an integer type, it tries to interpret the second argument as a number base and not as a number of decimal places.

So, in `String(100000, 0));`, it kind of thinks you're asking for the number to represented in the `String` in base 0 as opposed to decimal (`DEC`), hexadecimal (`HEX`), binary (`BIN`), etc and base 0 isn't a thing.

With a floating point type first argument like `1000.0` the second argument takes on the meaning of decimal places (seen an `decimalPlaces` in the documentation).

If you want `".00"` after an integer number when it's converted to a String it's probably better to just print it in a second `.print()` call, or to concatenate it to the string. And if you want you can manually type convert integer expressions to floating point type to force selection of the other constructor, e.g. `int a = 10000; whatever.print(String(float(a), 2));`